# Irreducible global Galois representation with weights 0, 1, 3?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Fix a prime number $p$. Can there exist a continuous irreducible representation $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to \mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ that is unramified at almost all primes, is de Rham at $p$ and whose Hodge-Tate weights at $p$ are 0, 1 and 3?

Comment: So I'm not a reputable source, eh? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two arguments for why such a representation $\rho$ cannot exist.

- Automorphic argument: Fontaine and Mazur have conjectured that any irreducible $n$-dimensional geometric representation $\rho$ of $Gal(\overline{\mathbf{Q}} / \mathbf{Q})$ comes from a cuspidal automorphic representation $\pi$ of $GL_n(\mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{Q}})$, and that "local-global compatibility at $\infty$" should hold, which amounts to saying that the Archimedean component $\pi_\infty$ should be determined by the Hodge–Tate weights of $\rho$ – up to a certain explicit shift, the multiset of Hodge–Tate weights of $\rho$ is the Harish-Chandra parameter of $\pi_\infty$. However, the possibilities for the representations $\pi_\infty$ which can show up as Archimedean components of automorphic representations are pretty restricted, so $(0, 1, 3)$ isn't possible. (This is essentially the argument sketched in David Hansen's comment from 2010 that you linked to.)
- Motivic argument: Fontaine and Mazur also made a (separate) conjecture that any such $\rho$ is the $p$-adic realisation of a pure motive over $\mathbf{Q}$. By the comparison isomorphism of Faltings–Tsuji relating étale and de Rham cohomology, this implies that the Hodge–Tate weights of $\rho$ give the graded pieces of a pure Hodge structure. Since a pure Hodge structure has a weight $w$ and an action of complex conjugation which switches the $(p, w-p)$ and $(w-p, p)$ parts, this means the set of weights must be symmetric around $w/2$.

Comment: thank you for your incredible answer! would you happen to have a precise reference (book or article, page number) for the automorphic Fontaine-Mazur conjecture? I have trouble locating it in the literature.

Comment: Fontaine and Mazur only stated the automorphic conjecture for $n = 2$. For the general version, see Conjecture 1.2.1 (4) of Patrikis' monograph "Variations on a theorem of Tate" (AMS Memoirs, 2019) -- you can find a pdf of it on Patrikis' website https://www.math.utah.edu/~patrikis/variationsrevision.pdf.

Comment: then do you know historically why is it attributed to these two guys? Did they state in a talk?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your motivic argument? I don't quite see how to deduce the symmetry of weights because we might be given an object of the category of motives over $\mathbb{Q}$ with coefficients in a field $F$ that has no real embeddings, so we are not getting a real Hodge structure out of it. For instance, if $K$ is a quadratic imaginary field of class number $1$ and $E$ is an elliptic curve over $K$ with CM by $K$ then the motive $h^1(Res_{K/\mathbb{Q}}E)$ splits into 4 motives of weights $0,0,1,1$ in the category of motives with coefficients in $K$.

Comment: I don't think I agree with your analysis of this CM elliptic curve example. It splits into 2 motives with $K$-coeffs, each of which has weight 1 and Hodge types \{ (0, 1), (1, 0) \}$. Both summands split further when you restrict them to motives *over $K$* with K-coefficients but that's a different thing.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right, I erroneously assumed that the Weil restrictions of these pieces split over $\mathbb{Q}$. So are you saying that in general even if an imaginary field is needed to split off the relevant motive, for some reason the symmetry will continue to hold on each piece?